# Identify time travel cartoon from clip

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, invisibility-cloak

From TVTropes article [Invisibility Cloak](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InvisibilityCloak)

At the bottom of the page there is a short clip from some animated show, featuring characters from several franchises. There's Doc and Marty from BTTF, Dr Evil, Hermionie, Doctor Who (I think), and I don't recognise the others.

What show does this come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a logo in the bottom right for "ArtSpear Entertainment" and "Toon Sandwich", I googled and found the [toon sandwich youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmv8PJ2JcIsHQ-2ivtziszQ). TV tropes has a [page on their "super-hero-bowl"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WebAnimation/SuperHeroBowl) which mentions that the episode "Super-Showdown-Bowl" featured the trope of time travel:

> Time Travel: Plays a pivotal theme in this round. In order to work out what Oscar's weakness is, and despite Oscar's efforts to thwart their plan, Marty McFly and Doc Brown arrive in their DeLorean and take the T-800, Doctor Strange, the Tenth Doctor, Bill & Ted, Dr. Evil and Hermione Granger back into the past.

The time travel stuff starts just after 18 minutes into the episode:

Comment: Thank you. (Bed time for me, I'll watch it tomorrow.)